# Cds photoresistor cells

Tags: electronics

We understand (from Wiki) that when light hits the photoresistor cell, the resistance goes down, electricity flows more easily.  But dont understand how resistance going down would work to turn OFF a light, like a streetlight.  How does a photocell work to turn off a light?  What exactly is the lowered resistance turning on?  Thanks

Comment: I would likely use a relay. If this were a question on the mechanism of photo conductivity it would be Physics. As it stands, it is more of an Electrical engineering question, suitable for their SE site.

Comment: The light is not going to be directly hooked up to the CdS photocell in series. Doubt that the resistance for a CdS photocell drops low enough for that to work and there are probably other issues with that as well. The photocell will act on the light through an electronic circuit. You can probably find some simple schematics of possible transistor designs to work with a CdS photocell and a small incandescent or LED light with a quick google search.

Comment: Jon-We ARE asking about the mechanism of photo conductivity.  What is the SE site if not this?  Thanks. Samuel- that helps!  Son is using a breadboard kit that is teaching all sorts of stuff, but leaving even more questions with its examples.

Comment: @Jenzan - If you want a simple, basic explanation of why the resistance of a photocell like CdS decreases, you can find one here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor . Basically, light photons cause the electrons in the CdS to "jump" across an energy gap and move, which lowers the cell's electrical resistance.

Comment: http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Control_Circuit/index184.html